# Filter HTML elements from HTML string with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to filter out different HTML tags from a string of HTML using jQuery. Here's what my code looks like right now:

```
$.get("check-in.php", {value: inputValue}).done(function(data) {
  var checkinSuccessStr = $("<p/>", { html: data }).find("#success").html();
  var checkinFailStr = $("<p/>", { html: data }).find("#fail").html();
  var tr = $("<tr/>", { html: data }).find("tr").html();

  console.log(checkinSuccessStr); // >> Success String
  console.log(checkinSuccessStr); // >> Failure String
  console.log(tr); // >> undefined
}
```

where `check-in.php` will render the following HTML:

```
"<p id='success'>Success String</p>
<p id='fail'>Failure String</p>
<tr><td>Table cell</td><td>Another cell</td></tr>"
```

Getting `checkinSuccessStr` and `checkinFailStr` in jQuery works fine, but not the table row. I've tried using `$.parseHTML` on the resulting `tr` variable, but no success. What can I do to get the `<tr>` element (or elements as an array or `<tr>`s ) from the HTML text, as either the string itself or the DOM element?

Answer (score 0):

**Answer:**

The HTML isn't fully valid because `<tr>` [must have](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tr) `<table>` (or `<thead>`, `<tbody>`, or `<tfoot>`) as a parent, so the parsed representation doesn't contain any `<tr>` tags.

Wrapping the `<tr>` in a `<table>` should fix the problem (ideally in the php, but, worst case, before parsing the string).

**Demo:**

You can see this in action by printing jQuery's parsed representation of the snippet with/without a `<table>` wrapper:

```js
console.log("Broken:", $(`
<p id='success'>Success String</p>
<p id='fail'>   Failure String</p>
<tr>
    <td>Table cell</td>
    <td>Another cell</td>
</tr>
`).find("tr").html());

console.log("Fixed:", $(`
<p id='success'>Success String</p>
<p id='fail'>   Failure String</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Another cell</td>
    </tr>
</table>
`).find("tr").html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
(Try running the snippet!)
```

Comment: I've tried using this: 

`var tableStr = $("<table/>", { html: data }).find("#result-table").html(); console.log(tableStr);` but no success. My HTML looks like this: `<table id='result-table'><tr><td>text</td><td>moretext</td></tr></table>`

Answer (score 0):

For parse broken table string use selector `'>'` like this:

```js
var part_table_str='<tr><td>Table cell</td><td>Another cell</td></tr>';
var cell_counter=0; //only for demonstration
$(part_table_str).find('>').each(function(){
   console.log('cell '+cell_counter+' => '+$(this).html());
   cell_counter++;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```